# C++: Counting the duplicates in a BST

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, binary-search-tree, traversal

I have a **BST** as;

```
    8
   / \
  4  12
   \
    6
   /
   6
```

I have the following code in order to calculate the duplicate count which in here should be 1 (6 has a duplicate);

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *left, *right;
};


void inorder(Node *root, Node *previous, int count)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        if(root != previous && root->data == previous->data)
            count++;
        previous = root;
        inorder(root->left, previous, count);
        cout<<root->data<<" ";
        inorder(root->right, previous, count);
    }
}
```

I have to do this **using constant extra space.**I know it's nowhere close but the idea I have is to keep a track of the previous node and check for the duplicate and at the end return the count. But I couldn't get to return an **integer** value while performing **in order BST traversal.**  Besides that would there be a better way to count the duplicates in BST. I initiate;

```
inorder(a, a, 0);
```

Comment: Probably store the traversal results in a vector, then find duplicates in the vector if you are not required to do it in place?

Comment: @taocp I have just edited the question. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Are you *not* counting multi-duplicates (i.e. if you have *three* `6` values in your tree, is it intended to be considered a "single value with duplicates" or should it be considered two "duplicates" (and in reality *three*, which is a much harder problem to solve)?

Comment: Why is your BST allowing duplicates?

Comment: @Ali I edited your problem to use constant extra space, that is the correct terminology for what you want

Answer (score 1):

In a binary search tree, depending on how the insert is written, the duplicate will always be on the left or right, looks like left in your case. So all you need is one extra variable that keeps track of the count of the dupes, in your function keep track of the last visited node if the current node is ever the same as the last visited one increment the count.

Here's some code **Disclaimer:** totally untested just know it compiles

```
int count_dupes(Node * root, Node * last = nullptr) {
    int is_dupe = 0;
    if (root->value == last->value) is_dupe = 1;
    return is_dupe + (root->right != nullptr? count_dupes(root->right,root):0)
        + (root->left!= nullptr? count_dupes(root->left,root):0);
}
```

By the way I'm sensing this is an interview type question but Thomas Matthews is right, your tree should not have duplicates inserted.

Comment: Either that, or a homework. Probably a homework, so I chose not to provide code :)

Comment: @AlexK I don't even know if it works all I know is it compiles

Comment: @AlexK also I answered like 30mins ago and no UV's so figured I'd post some code

Comment: I feel like comparing root->value == last->value on line 2, when last is a sent in as a nullptr will cause a seg fault...

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume in your BST a duplicate can only be on the left of a node (it is always the same side, we just have to choose the convention and stick to it). Just increment duplicate count as you recurse left in your in-order traversal and value does not change. Make sure you pass count by reference, not by value. Zero it out before starting. Nice interview question, btw

Comment: The OP never came back